# velocity localization configuration

Tags: struts-config

here my struts configuration

```
<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
<constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="ApplicationResources"/>
<constant name="struts.locale" value="ms_MY" />
<constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="200097152" />
```

this configuration for *.properties

but for *.vm i dont know how to configure it.

please help me.